# Navigating to a specific tab with Angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm using query params to navigate to a specific tab between components. The receiving component (which needs to check the query params) keeps returning the error:

`Cannot set property active of undefined`

In one component, I have the following html.

```
<button *ngIf="isLoggedInUser" style="position: absolute; right: 0" class="btn btn-link btn-sm"
            [routerLink]="['/users/' + auth.currentUser.id + '/edit']" [queryParams]="{tab: 2}">
            <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
</button>
```

In the edit component (the one checking the query params), I have this in my ngOnInit using `ActivatedRoute`.

```
this.router.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  const selectedTab = params["tab"];
  console.log(this.editProfileTabs);
  this.editProfileTabs.tabs[
    selectedTab > 0 ? selectedTab : 0
  ].active = true;
});
```

When I try it...i get this in the console:

```
core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'active' of undefined
```

any ideas? I would think the ternary would handle null/undefined stuff.

I've console logged the tabset and it does log tabs in that html group.

[image]

Comment: Check the content of `this.editProfileTabs`, this probably doesn't have values the index you are trying to fetch.

Comment: Good idea. I did. Console shows tabs. See updated post with screenshot.

Comment: Problem with this debugging is, console logs are lazy and evaluated late. Under `queryParams` subscription, try logging like: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.editProfileTabs)))`.

Comment: ah. Yes. Now there are only 2 tabs in the tabset array at indexes 0 & 1. So index 2 doesn't exist. Ideas on how to fix?

Comment: How do you get value into `this.editProfileTabs`? What populates this property?

Comment: It's an ngx-bootstrap tabset with a template id of #editProfileTabs hard-coded into the html. However, out of the 4 possible tabs, two have an *ngIf on them so they're only rendered if the user is a certain type of user based on the model. There is a resolver on this component to load the user before the component loads.

Comment: Try adding the `this.router.queryParams.subscribe()` in `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: Visibly works, but get this console error. ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'active: undefined'. Current value: 'active: true'.

Comment: There could be two ways to fix this. 1st (preferrable): If this `active` property is used inside only under the current componnets HTML binding then simply inject `ChangeDetectorRef` in the current component and after you have assigned value to `active`, call `this._detectorInstance.detectChanges()`. 2nd. If `active` binding is used in some other component's HTML too then easiest way is to assign the value to `active` under a `setTimeout(() => { // assign here })`. (There is some other way to fix this too, but that would be messy and I would rather prefer this.)

Comment: Yeah. I found a blog post about it and just added a setTimeout. Worked fine and easiest solution I can tell. Thanks for all the help.You should write this as a solution so I can upvote it for you.

Comment: But still, follow the first suggestion if it applies. `setTimeout()` calls change detection for the whole app while a `detectChanges()` will call only for the current component and its children.

Comment: Got detectChanges() working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference variables are loaded into the component in under `ngAfterViewInit()` life cycle hook. So if you are accessing it in your ".ts" then do it under `ngAfterViewInit()`.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.router.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.editProfileTabs.tabs[selectedTab > 0 ? selectedTab : 0].active = true;
    });
}
```

In the development mode, angular does two checks so if you change property which is bound to HTML under `ngAfterViewInit()` then you in the second check you will be getting errors like:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

To fix this, you should run change detection manually. Inject `ChangeDetectorRef` in the component and use it like:

```
constructor(private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    .....
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.router.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.editProfileTabs.tabs[selectedTab > 0 ? selectedTab : 0].active = true;
        this._cdr.detectChanges()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this code

```
ngAfterViewInit() {    
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        const selectedTab = params["tab"];
        this.editProfileTabs.selectedIndex = selectedTab > 0 ? selectedTab : 0;
    });
}
```